# How can I format the date displayed from an api?

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

I'm pulling data from an api and want to change the format of the date displayed. What's the best way to achieve this? Do I implement something at the point where I retrieve the data or the point where it is displayed?

```
import axios from 'axios'
import {popularGamesURL, upcomingGamesURL, newGamesURL} from '../api'


export const loadGames = () => async (dispatch) => {
    const popularData = await axios.get(popularGamesURL());
    const newGamesData = await axios.get(newGamesURL());
    const upcomingData = await axios.get(upcomingGamesURL());
    dispatch({
        type: "FETCH_GAMES",
        payload: {
            popular: popularData.data.date.results,
            upcoming: upcomingData.data.results,
            newGames: newGamesData.data.results,
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install moment js in your project. It is one of the best library, giving you the best result. I'd recommend you to format it while displaying. I dont see any point of doing it while retrieving.

moment js will do the date formation. moment(your actual date).format(format you are looking for).

please read api documentation at https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Date formatting is a display stuff, so you should put it in your view.

Check out this beautiful answer for some tips on formatting dates in js:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3552493/938227